# Angular Radio button set checked to first input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just built a dynamic (data from API) form which includes an ng-repeat to produce a load of radio buttons. It works fine, but I'm having difficulties setting the first radio button to be checked. Can anyone help?

```
<div ng-repeat="carrier in options.shipping.methods">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" id="{{ carrier.slug }}" name="{{ carrier.slug }}" value="{{ carrier.slug }}" ng-model="data.shipping" />
        <label class="radio" for="{{ carrier.slug }}">{{ carrier.description }}</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Can I set `ng-init` to `$index == 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `checked` attribute to the input when you need it by using ngChecked.

check this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

```
<div ng-repeat="carrier in options.shipping.methods">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" id="{{ carrier.slug }}" name="{{ carrier.slug }}" value="{{ carrier.slug }}" ng-model="data.shipping"  ngChecked="carrier.isSelected" />
        <label class="radio" for="{{ carrier.slug }}">{{ carrier.description }}</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

In your controller you will do something like

```
$scope.options.shipping.methods[0].isSelected = true;
```

**OR** you can write the check directly in the ngChecked

```
ngChecked="carrier.someProperty != null"
```

Comment: That will work if it was a list of radio buttons, but as it is a ng-repeat, and the passed data could be any random order, thats not going to work to well as it will put ng-checked onto all radio buttons.

Comment: @Tomaltach in carrier add a boolean property and give it to ngChecked
then you can control which one should be checked by passing true

Comment: Yes that should work. I was mistaken with the normal checked attribute

Comment: @Tomaltach vote and mark my answer as the correct answer